# Sudo command locked

Tags: sudo, user-management, user-profile

I have problem, when I try to use `sudo` command I **immediately** get these messages:

```
Sorry, try again. 
Sorry, try again.  
Sorry, try again.  
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

There's no chance to enter anything before they appear.

Comment: Are you using the correct password?

Comment: I can't write password, i get that all messages before i could enter the password.

Comment: Its more annoying to say that terminal don't give me chance to write password. It's first time I'm using terminal. It just happened that something went wrong and i can't write password.

Comment: Your description is very unclear, did Pelle's answer really solve your problem? I read your comment on that answer as "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this when using ldap, as a workaround I've set the NOPASSWD option in /etc/sudoers. I never did find out the root cause.

log in as root and run

```
visudo
```

and change the line

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(your group may not be named sudo but admin or something else)

WARNING: this setting means you will never be asked for a password when using sudo, making it easier to accidentally break your system

Comment: Could you gimme more details how to do that? I'm newbie with ubuntu.

Comment: When i write visudo i get /etc/sudoers Read-only file system.

Fix: mount -o remount,rw /

Answer (score 0):

If everything else failed and nothing worked, reboot the system, but hold down the shift key and it'll take you to the grub listing where you can jump into recovery mode.

At that point, you will be able to drop to root and then you can execute this: `passwd thisuser` and the system will reset the lock and ask for new password (and confirmation on 2nd attempt).  Once that's done, log out and reboot entirely.

`thisuser` = `your actual username`

Then everything should work as expected.  Meanwhile, I would like to point out about adding username in /etc/sudoers is something I would not recommend, based on my experience several years ago where I saw that it's kinda more than dangerous to have your username listed in sudoers file.  That file isn't meant to be edited nor customized at all.